# How to get only key values into array using mongoldb?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I trying to use get only values from Mongodb query results in to array.

My query is

```
db.collection_name.find({"actual_time":{"$gt": start_date, "$lte": end_date}}, {'_id': False})
```

and my result is

```
    {
   "result": [
       {
           "start": 7299.69,
           "end": 7299.73,
           "low": 7297.38,
           "open": 7297.84,
           "time": 1536007500,
           "volumefrom": 16.98,
           "volumeto": 123447.27,
       },
       {
           "start": 7307.24,
           "end": 7308.11,
           "low": 7299.69,
           "open": 7299.69,
           "time": 1536007680,
           "volumefrom": 78.7,
           "volumeto": 575049.25,
       }
    ]
}
```

But I don't want this result. I want to get result as below

```
    {
   "result": [
       {
          7299.69,
          7299.73,
          7297.38,
          7297.84,
          1536007500,
          16.98,
          123447.27,
       },
       {
          7307.24,
          7308.11,
          7299.69,
          7299.69,
          1536007680,
          78.7,
          575049.25,
       }
    ]
}
```

How to write the query in Mongodb?

Comment: this is not valid json...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below aggregation in 3.4.

Use [`$let`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/) with [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) on [`$$ROOT`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/#system-variables) to extract the key values.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {"$match":{"actual_time":{"$gt":start_date,"$lte":end_date}}},
  {"$project":{
    "_id":0,
    "keyvalues":{
      "$let":{
        "vars":{"dockv":{
         "$filter":{
          "input":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"},
          "cond":{"$not":{"$in":["$$this.k",["_id"]]}}
          }
         }},
        "in":"$$dockv.v"
      }
    }
  }},
 {"$group":{"_id":null,"results":{"$push":"$keyvalues"}}}
])
```

Comment: this query not working your query result show different.

Comment: What is your expected result ?

Comment: result getting 
`{‘keyvalues’: [ObjectId(‘5b8e29615664ee18676e0621’), 7307.24, 7308.11, 7299.69, 7299.69, 1536007680, 78.7, 575049.25]}
{‘keyvalues’: [ObjectId(‘5b8e29615664ee18676e0621’), 7307.24, 7308.11, 7299.69, 7299.69, 1536007680, 78.7, 575049.25]}`

Comment: I mention on my question what I am expected result

Comment: Updated answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: this line `{"$group":{"_id":null,"results":{"$push":"$keyvalues"}}}` shown error `':' expected `

Comment: Sorry. Misplaced group. Please try now.